# How to parse txt.file with no clear separator

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, text

I am trying to parse a txt.file that has a known structure.
Each column represent a country and each value the frequency in which the name is used in this country.

More info about the source plus original doc [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/searching-for-lists-of-babynames-containing-huge-10k-amounts-of-unique-name/4757#4757) - it is called nam_dict.txt

It look like this:

```
M  Aadam                                          1                                   $
F  Aadje                                1                                             $
M  Ådne                      +                 1                                      $
M  Aadu                                           12                                  $
?F Aaf                                  1                                             $
F  Aafke                                4                                             $
?  Aafke                                 1                                            $
F  Aafkea                                1                                            $
M  Aafko                                1                                             $
M  Aage                                       761                                     $
M  Åge                       +                56                                      $
F  Aagje                              1 2                                             $
```

Problem is that there is no separator between digits and any figure for a given column could have one or two digits (1 to 13). Is there a good way to extract this?

I would like to do this with Python and Pandas.

Columns are as follows:

```
['GreatBritain',
 'Ireland',
 'U.S.A.',
 'Italy',
 'Malta',
 'Portugal',
 'Spain',
 'France',
 'Belgium',
 'Luxembourg',
 'theNetherlands',
 'EastFrisia',
 'Germany',
 'Austria',
 'Swiss',
 'Iceland',
 'Denmark',
 'Norway',
 'Sweden',
 'Finland',
 'Estonia',
 'Latvia',
 'Lithuania',
 'Poland',
 'CzechRepublic',
 'Slovakia',
 'Hungary',
 'Romania',
 'Bulgaria',
 'BosniaandHerzegovina',
 'Croatia',
 'Kosovo',
 'Macedonia',
 'Montenegro',
 'Serbia',
 'Slovenia',
 'Albania',
 'Greece',
 'Russia',
 'Belarus',
 'Moldova',
 'Ukraine',
 'Armenia',
 'Azerbaijan',
 'Georgia',
 'Kazakhstan/Uzbekistan,etc.',
 'Turkey',
 'Arabia/Persia',
 'Israel',
 'China',
 'India/SriLanka',
 'Japan',
 'Korea',
 'Vietnam',
 'othercountries']
```

Hoping to get to this type of output (with numbers where appropriate):

```
    gender  GreatBritain    Ireland U.S.A.  Italy   Malta   Portugal    Spain   France  Belgium ... Kazakhstan/Uzbekistan,etc.  Turkey  Arabia/Persia   Israel  China   India/SriLanka  Japan   Korea   Vietnam othercountries
name                                                                                    
Aad M   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Aadam   M   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Aadje   F   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Ådne    M   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Aadu    M   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespaces can be combined:
`df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s+")`

E.g. several consequent whitespaces will be treated as single delimiter.

Update: Seems like you ought to use `read_fwf`

```
>>> df = pd.read_fwf('nam_dict.txt', header=None, skiprows=362)
>>> df.head()
  0      1    2    3    4    5    6   7   8   9   10   11  12 13
0  M    Aad  NaN  NaN  NaN    4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  $
1  M  Aadam  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  $
2  F  Aadje  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  $
3  M   Ådne    +  NaN  NaN  NaN    1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  $
4  M   Aadu  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   12 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  $
>>> df.shape
(48528, 14)
```

Update2: Had to generate list of columns. Width of 1st column=1, second = 27 (until the + sign), and remaining ones set to 1. Check and amend, if needed:

```
>>> cols = [2, 27]
>>> cols.extend([1]*58)
>>> df = pd.read_fwf('nam_dict.txt', header=None, skiprows=362, widths=cols)
>>> df.head()
  0      1    2    3   4   5    6    7    8    9  ...   50  51   52  53  54  \
0  M    Aad  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...  NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN
1  M  Aadam  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...  NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN
2  F  Aadje  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...  NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN
3  M   Ådne    +  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...  NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN
4  M   Aadu  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...  NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN

    55   56  57  58 59
0  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  $
1  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  $
2  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  $
3  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  $
4  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  $

[5 rows x 60 columns]
```

Comment: what do you mean that they can be combined? I tried your suggestion and I get ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 14, saw 12

Comment: OK it matches any non-whitespace character - does not solve my problem though as figures could appear in different locations and I want to keep the structure, the location where the number is has a meaning that I am interested to retrieve

Comment: @MthClv Try `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf` then

Comment: pd.read_fwf('nam_dict.txt') squashes everything into one column - structure is lost as well

Comment: Actually pd.read_fwf('nam_dict.txt', skiprows=362, header=None) returns 14 columns yes but I should have 55 - problem is that digits that are next to each other are understood as one number

Comment: To be exact: nb cols is 58 if we add gender, name and $ sign